VS Code Azure Function Debugging Hangs
Currently developing an azure function using VS code. I have installed the Azure Function extension as well as the latest version of Azure Core tools. I have basically followed this down to the letter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python
When attempting to debug the function I can successfully do so ONCE. If the function has an error or I disconnect the debugger using the GUI, or kill the terminal in VS code, any additional attempts at running the debugger just show the blue progress bar spinning indefinitely. I have some co-workers who are not experiencing this, but they were setup for Azure functions months ago. I am wondering if I have a new version of something causing this. We have compared the project .json files to make sure settings are the same. I have a couple of additional options that were auto generated by the newer version of the tools im using I am assuming. There was a simliar question asked but the answer is not helpful. I am on Windows as well.
vs code azure function - debugging 2nd time
Options in my files that are not in my coworkers:
local.settings.json
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
This is part of the documentation from the microsoft link above.
.vscode/settings.json
"azureFunctions.projectLanguageModel": 2
I have uninstalled/reinstalled both the azure function extension and azure core tools.
I have attempted to remove the additional options in my files but that leads to errors when running the function. I have also uninstalled the azure function extension and azure core tools and reinstalled.

It sounds like your launch.json file doesn't have a postDebugTask to stop the functions host. Your launch.json should look something like this:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Azure Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "startAzureFunctions",
            "postDebugTask": "stopAzureFunctions",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/azure-functions-host",
            "args": [
                "start"
            ],
            "env": {
                "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your_storage_connection_string>",
                "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "startAzureFunctions",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/azure-functions-host start",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "stopAzureFunctions",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/azure-functions-host stop",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}


I will try this. Thanks for the help. I will say the files generated by the extensions etc. are not near this robust. It seems like it should be included like this if its the difference in working and not working....
